# IntelliJ Unable to utilize GRADLE_OPTS

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradlew

I have `GRADLE_OPTS` exported in my profile which includes vm parameters for a java key store (jks) including a self signed certificate.

```
export GRADLE_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/userdummy/Desktop/truststore.jks \
                  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"
```

If I run gradle wrapper manually from terminal there is no problem. But ide itself is unable to access to the trusted artifactory site. PKIX error occurred.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-253331/GRADLEOPTS-not-picked-up-by-builds-triggered-via-IDE